# Excel query regarding IF statements

Tags: excel, if-statement, math, nested

I think this should be a fairly quick question, hopefully!

I would like to add a line to the following formula, after the line that says IF C6 =0,0 that if B6 is equal to W, the result should be 9.95:

```
=IF(C6=0,0,
MAX(SUM(IF(F6<=0,0,39),
IF(F6>30,(C6*0.08),
IF(F6>20,(C6*0.07),
IF(F6>10,(C6*0.06),
IF(F6>5,(C6*0.05),
IF(F6>2,(C6*0.04),
IF(F6>1,(C6*0.03),
IF(F6>=0.25,(C6*0.02),

IF(F6>=0,(0.03*C6*F6),0))))))))),43))
```

Basically, the first thing it should look for is that if C6 is 0, the result should be 0 - but if C6 > 0, then to check B6 for the letter 'W', and if that is true, then to display 9.95, otherwise to go along with the remainder of the formula.

Comment: Could you substitute a vlookup for all of those ifs?  I can't help but notice the values seem to represent ranges, which might fit nicely with a vlookup.

Comment: I'm not nearly as good with Excel as I'd like to be; what would that entail/look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
=IF(C6=0,0,
IF(B6="W",9.95,
MAX(SUM(IF(F6<=0,0,39),
IF(F6>30,(C6*0.08),
IF(F6>20,(C6*0.07),
IF(F6>10,(C6*0.06),
IF(F6>5,(C6*0.05),
IF(F6>2,(C6*0.04),
IF(F6>1,(C6*0.03),
IF(F6>=0.25,(C6*0.02),
IF(F6>=0,(0.03*C6*F6),0))))))))),43)))
```